# Get all objects defined by a Django ManyToManyField relationship

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

The site I'm building allows users to create "posts" and has a Twitter-like concept of followed users. For a given user, I'd like to show all of the posts from the users that they follow.

Here are my simplified models:

```
class User
    # a standard django.contrib.auth user model

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE for django-profiles
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name="followed_by")

class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.TextField()
```

**Question:** How do you create a queryset of all Post objects from the Users that a given User is following?

I think I've made it more complicated by creating the "follow" relationship on UserProfile, which is not the model with the ForeignKey relationship with Posts.

**UPDATE! Here's the answer:**

```
Posts.objects.filter(user__userprofile__in=UserProfile.objects.get(user=your_user_object).following.all())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Posts.objects.filter(user__in=UserProfile.objects.get(user=your_user_object).following)
```

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: oh, i forgot. After "following" add .all(), like "UserProfile.objects.get(user=your_user_object).following.all()". If it doesn't work, change it to following.objects.all(). I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the TypeError, but something still isn't quite right as it is returning an empty set.

Comment: maybe it's just empty "following" field of an specified user?

Comment: The user I'm testing is following 3 users who have created a total of 32 posts. I think it may be looking for a User object in a set of UserProfiles?